# Animated PNG looping on IOS

Tags: javascript, animation, animated-gif

I'm having an issue where an animaed png that is encoded to only play once, plays twice on IOS. I am swapping out a blank PNG to the animated PNG when it gets within viewport. Once in viewport since its on scroll it checks to see if the src of the image is the animated or static. If its the static it doesn't do a swap.

On desktop its perfect. But on mobile the animation plays twice. I thought it was my js but it turns out the png itself is acting differently in IOS.

I checked out the direct url to the animation and it turns out even though the PNG is set to play only once on IOS it plays twice.

The PNG in quesiton is used here: https://www.xeroproject.com/wtf/
And the direct link is here: https://www.xeroproject.com/wtf/wp-content/themes/wtf_big5/images/arrow_animate.png

WHen you scroll down to the map an arrow animates and map markers fall in. Again, Desktop perfect but on ios it animates twice. Same goes for going to the direct link.

Is there a different way to encode it I can use? or is this something I can't control in IOS?

Comment: I am having the same exact problem on Safari IOS, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: The client eventually changed their mind about the animation all togheter so I never found a solution.